# $G$ has Kazhdan's property (T) $\iff$ $G$ has a Kazhdan pair

Tags: group-theory, functional-analysis

A locally compact group $G$ is said to be Kazhdan or have Property (T)  if for any unitary representation $\rho$ that has almost invariant vectors (a.i.v) it has an invariant vector.
Meaning of a.i.v - for all $K \subseteq G$ compact and $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a $(K, \epsilon)$ invariant vector -  $\left\lVert v \right\rVert =1$ such that $$\left\lVert\rho (g)v-v \right\rVert < \epsilon$$

$(K, \epsilon)$ is said to be a Kazhdan pair if for all unitary representations of $G$ that has a $(K, \epsilon)$ invariant vector it has an invariant vector.

Apparently $G$ is Kazhdan if and only if it has a Kazhdan pair.

It's easy to see that existence of Kazhdan pair implies Kazhdan, but I did not manage to prove the opposite direction. I know that $G$ is compactly generated and that if I can show that $G$ has a $(K,\epsilon)$ invariant vector for all $\epsilon>0$ and for the generating set $K$ then I'm finished, but I don't know haw to choose my $\epsilon$.

I hope I was clear, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $G$ has no Kazhdan pair. For every $(K,\varepsilon)$ choose a unitary representation $\pi_{K,\varepsilon}$ that negates $(K,\varepsilon)$ being a Kazhdan pair. Then consider $\pi=\bigoplus_{K,\varepsilon}\pi_{K,\varepsilon}$, the orthogonal direct sum of all these representation. Then $\pi$ negates $G$ being Kazhdan.

(Exercise: fill in details.)

Comment: Do we need the assumption that $G$ is locally compact anywhere? Or is it enough to assume that $G$ is a topological group?

Comment: @TheTralfamadorian you're right, it seems (Hausdorff) topological group is OK